# android: notify on gmail email with specific label income

Tags: android, gmail, android-notifications, gmail-api

My app can send emails (*Gmail*) to other users.
The problem is that I'd like to let the user know that the email he just received is from my app.
I could do a notification service but I would prefer not as there are already tons of apps with running services and notifications.

Is there a way to catch the incoming of a *gmail* email with a certain label or subject or from address ?

I ask this because it looks so stupid to create another notification service when it's already there.

edit: added **gmail-api** tag

Comment: Please make it more clear. Your application can send Gmail (through coding) to other user. And you did like to let the user (mail receiver) know that the mail comes from your application. right ?

Comment: @BuildSuccess: Yep, exactly. I'd like to show a notification when an email with a specific subject/label was received but without adding a new notification service (an incoming email already generates an alert so why reinventing the wheel ?). I've seen that there are Gmail APIs for this but it's not really clear if what I need is possible.

Comment: NotificationListenerService seems to be the right candidate, I'll give it a try.

Comment: check bellow. link:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm Did you need something like this ?

Comment: No, I already send email to users. I need to show a notification when an email comes. I tried NotificationListenerService but it requires a security permission that is too big ("app" will be able to read ALL notifications, etc ...). I would not install an app with such a permission.